# Import activity failures

Tags: automation, import

I'm running into an error with an automated import that is causing the upload to fail. The system says "Warning: Import aborted while processing Batch 1 in DsvFileSourceReader."

The error code is FieldNotFound with the designation 52, which is the last column in the csv file that I am uploading. The field is nullable and mapped correctly. The import fails regardless of whether values are placed in Column 52.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In can only be possible on following reasons:

- FieldAPI is incorrect in mapping table.
- Field is not found is target organization

It has been assumed that, user (who is loading the data) has access to the field via, field level security.